# how to use CamelSpringTestSupport

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel, junit4

I would like to use CamelSpringTestSupport in order to test my camel route.
this is my camelContext :

```
<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
  <propertyPlaceholder id="incomingFileHandlerP"
    location="classpath:incomingFileHandler.properties" />
  <route>
    <from uri="file://{{filesBaseDir}}?recursive=true&amp;move=.done" id="incomingFile"/>
    <convertBodyTo type="java.lang.String" />
    <to uri="bean:incomingFileHandler" id="incomingFileHandlerBean"/>

    <log message='${exchangeProperty[incomingFileHandlerError]}' />
    <choice>
      <when>
        <simple>${exchangeProperty[incomingFileHandlerError]} != 'null'
        </simple>
        <log message="incomingFileHandler error" />
        <to uri="file://?fileName=C:/tmp/xxx.xml" />
      </when>
      <otherwise>
        <to uri="file://?fileName=C:/tmp/yyy.xml" />
      </otherwise>
    </choice>
  </route>
</camelContext>
```

I want to be able to test (assert tests) the Exchange paremeters values after returning from incomingFileHandlerBean.

So I have this Junit skeleton class:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class Tests extends CamelSpringTestSupport {

  @Test
  public void test() throws InterruptedException {
    ////// ??
  }

  @Override
  protected AbstractApplicationContext createApplicationContext() {
    return new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("file:src/main/resources/META-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml");
  }
}
```

But I'm not sure how to fill the test method.
I do not want to copy the file content to the sendBodyAndHeader parameter. I would like to get the content by camel reading the file from the file system.
I will be happy for any help.

Comment: Yes please spend more time yourself study more about Apache Camel and how to test, there are examples with tests, website, blogs, books, videos etc.

Comment: The nominated close reason ("request for off-site resource") is incorrect.  Being about basic knowledge is not by itself a valid close reason, which may be why the voter had to pick a reason that doesn't make any sense.  In addition, "RTFM" is an inappropriate comment on SO: it is snarky and hints that questions about basic topics are not wanted here--something that is just untrue.

Comment: See also: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253473/should-we-add-rtfm-to-the-list-of-off-topic-close-reasons

Comment: "RTFM" or "spend more time studying" don't apply to documentation like Camel's that's written like release notes. Imagine going to a restaurant and asking "what's the special for today?", only to be told by the server the special for the day before, and the week before and the month before. No one gives a dang about what the previous versions of a software did - they are already on a particular version. If the committers can't take the time to version the docs, no wonder people reading it end up confused.
Too bad comments don't have downvotes.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar SO aims to be a canonical collection of questions and answers.  That is why it allows questions that are in the documentation--even basic questions.  If a question does not already exist, and there is no close reason that applies to it, then it must stand.  That said, it is possible that this question is too broad--many "write the code for me" questions are.  I don't know the subject matter, so I cannot judge.  What I am absolutely certain about, however, is that RTFM is not valid on SO.

Comment: Well, the same question was cross-posted to the Apache Camel mailing-list and they also replied with basically RTFM: http://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/how-to-use-CamelSpringTestSupport-td5805805.html If the OP lacks understanding certain aspects of Camel testing the question has to be asked differently to narrow the focus on the actual issue. In its current form, however, it is more like "please write me a unit-test for the given route definition". Even if s/he gets an answers, it is questionable if they will help clarify the necessary steps involved.

Comment: the RTFM answer in this case is completely inappropriate IMO.  Having worked with Camel for years, I will say the documentation is generally terrible if not completely broken in some areas (bad links, etc).  To illustrate this point further, by the author's own admission a large portion of the Apache Camel 3.0 release is simply to fix the state of the documentation of this project.  If the author(s) of a project can't write adequate/clear documentation, the least they can do is answer the questions of those having to wade through it.  A project is only as good as its documentation/community.

Comment: I read all the FM (and much more)  and still do not succeed in writing a single test. The long tail of examples for different versions does not help. I would like to see a simple example for each version.

Answer (score 1):

Might be a little late but I stumbled across this question while having to deal with camel tests myself and found a way that might help you:

You could place a mock component (`<to uri="mock:myMock" />`) right after the desired endpoint (your bean in this case) and access it from the test function (**it's important that you define the mock and the expectatinos before starting the route**):

```
MockEndpoint mock = getMockEndpoint("mock:myMock");
mock.expectedBodiesReceived("Hi");
mock.expectedHeaderReceived("Field", "Value");
// starting the route here
mock.assertIsSatisfied();
```

Alternatively you could use a processor there that uses assertions but if an assertion fails the whole thing breaks with an ugly exceptino and you don't really know what assertion failed with what:

```
public class TestProcessor implements Processor{

    @Override
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Hi vom processor"); // Printed to console
        Assert.assertEquals("Assert in processor failed","Expected",exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class));
    }
}
```

Here's my entire example:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"    
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd        
        http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd">

     <bean id="TestProcessor" class="util.TestProcessor" />
     <camelContext id="mytestroute" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
            <route>
                <from uri="direct:start" />
                <to uri="mock:intermediate" />
                <to uri="bean:TestProcessor" /> 
                <to uri="mock:end" />
            </route>
       </camelContext>
</beans>
```

The test class:

```
public class NewClass extends CamelSpringTestSupport {

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {

        MockEndpoint mock = getMockEndpoint("mock:end");
        MockEndpoint intermediate= getMockEndpoint("mock:intermediate");
        mock.expectedBodiesReceived("Hi");
        intermediate.expectedBodiesReceived("Hello");
        template.sendBody("direct:start", "Hello");
        mock.assertIsSatisfied();
        intermediate.assertIsSatisfied();
    }

    @Override
    protected AbstractApplicationContext createApplicationContext() {
        // The context file is in my test/resources folder
        return new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("camelTestContext.xml");
    }
}
```